# android edit text design - remove edit text line bottom padding & change text and line between padding

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

I have some issues in android ui design.

[image]

This is an editText.
I have to remove (1) padding and change padding size of (2).
(1) is a padding between underline and border,
(2) is a padding between text and underline.
And currently this editText's android:includeFontPadding="false" now.

Fast answer please!

Comment: Create Custom underLine Drawable. for that you to create three drawable file and you can do anything with the help of this drawable file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:background="@null" // removes underline
    android:lines="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"        
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/lineTwo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"  //change this line as you need
    android:background="@android:color/white" 
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etEmail" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thanks you for your answer! but now i have to use edit text bottom line selector. when user input some text in there, change colors. than should I have to change line color in activity codes?

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/xyZ"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:lines="1" />
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.